# Are model versions unnecessary for NSInMemoryStoreType in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

Are there any good reasons to version models that are exclusively used for `NSInMemoryStoreType` stores? Without persistence, versioning seems unnecessary except for maybe documentation purposes. As migrations are handled outside of the scope of the data model, it's obvious why the option is available, but is there some quirk of Core Data that I might be overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use in-memory stores, there's no reason to bother with model migration. Core Data uses model migration to update a persistent store to use a new data model. With an in-memory store the store isn't really persistent, since the app creates a new one every time it runs, so there's no existing data to migrate.